# Error while compiling Linux in make menuconfig on Fedora

Tags: c, linux

How do I resolve the following error when compiling Linux in make menuconfig on Fedora:

```
$ make menuconfig
Makefile:323: /home/user/linux-3.12.6/scripts/Kbuild.include: No such file or directory

make: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the kernel-devel package if you want to compile something against the kernel. If you want to compile the kernel yourself, you'll have to get the source package for it (or fetch a kernel source from kernel.org).

Answer (score 1):

First I would go to the directory `/home/user/linux-3.12.6/scripts/` and see if the file `Kbuild.include` is present.  If it is not, you may need to download the source again.  Perhaps there was an error while downloading.